# Django+MongoDB vs Node.js+MongoDB

Tags: django, node.js, mongodb

I have up and running a website with sync services that built using Python(Django)+MySQL. For a long time I'm looking to the Node.js and MongoDB side. I'm close to make a decision to move to MongoDB part of the system that hosts data from user's desktop clients and used by sync service to sync data between clients.

I'd like to keep the rest of the system running on Django+MySQL.

My question is should I rewrite sync service on Node.js or keep it running on Django? Is there any advantages for Node.js with MongoDB against Django?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you're looking for performance, Node.js should have a better performance against Django. But Node.js runs async, you should prepare the code for that, if you need everything sync and up, maybe Django is the best choice, because you already have it running.

But if you choose Node.js, make something that make the fact of beeing async is no problem for you and your data consistency, like message queues.

Check this out, it has the pros and cons of each one

[switch python to node.js](http://journal.paul.querna.org/articles/2011/12/18/the-switch-python-to-node-js/)

[tornado, django and node.js benchmark](http://swizec.com/blog/benchmarking-node-tornado-and-django-for-concurrency/swizec/1616)

Comment: Thanks for the comment and links. Async is no problem for me.

Comment: but do we have to look for single threaded language(Node js) vs multi threaded language(python)?