# Can I use the same MongoDB database from Python and NodeJS

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, mongodb, database

I would like to know if it would be possible to use MongoDB in the following way:

I want the database to be populated and modified from a script written in Python and to be queried from Node JS.

Is it possible? If yes, Does this approach have any kind of compatibility problems or inefficiencies?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't see why this wouldn't be possible since you're just creating one extra connection to the database.

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13067682/djangomongodb-vs-node-jsmongodb

Comment: And this https://journal.paul.querna.org/articles/2011/12/18/the-switch-python-to-node-js/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yup, it's possible unless you mess up with the schema. Cause mongo won't complain for different types of objects in the same collection.

I would suggest using [**mongoose**](http://mongoosejs.com/) for Node.js and [**pymongo**](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/) for python. You can easily install pymongo by doing - `pip install pymongo` in linux and osx systems. But for window I think u will have to do it manually from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymongo/).

I think reading the documentation for each of them would give you a better idea. You can also take a look at [getting started with mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/shell/). You will find how to use it in many different language.

Thanks!!

Comment: Hey Thank you! I started reading what you suggested and also this little book: http://openmymind.net/mongodb.pdf -> I think it could be useful for future beginners like me.

Comment: @juanM. Great! I guess I would read that too. Hope it would give me some information too...

Comment: Where would you define the Schema for the validator?  If you define it inside mongoose, then you cannot use it in Python. If you define it in Python (as a dictionary), then you cannot use it in mongoose.  I would assume you need some sort of XML file that both can load up?  Any suggestions on that?